# Split C char* for Spreadsheet Cell Reference

Tags: c

To outline: I have a parser that grabs Cell references using the following regex

"$"?{letter}{1,2}"$"?{digit}{1,3}

I cant seem to find an elegant way to split the resulting char* into its row, and column components.

ex. split a1 into a and 1 
          or 
split $aa$4 into fixed_col a fixed row 4

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a regex library?  If so does it support accessing grouped parts of the regex, something like:

```
("$"?)({letter})({1,2})("$"?)({digit}{1,3})
```

(This [article](http://www.developer.com/net/net/article.php/3490231) shows the technique using the .NET regex library)

If that isn't an option, then building a simple state machine would work well, and be easy to maintain and test.